# VBA code to search and open file at 2 locations

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to open a SAP file (C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe) i also want to include the path (C:\Program Files\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe) in same code to search at either location and open it

code is:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim sapConn As Object

Set objshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objapp = objshell.Exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe")
Set sapConn = CreateObject("SAP.Functions") 'Create ActiveX object

        sapConn.Connection.ApplicationServer = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"
        sapConn.Connection.Client = "100" ' only read access


End Sub
```

Comment: How about using On Error Resume Next and attempting to launch both paths?

Answer (score 0):

How about checking if the folder exists before running the program:

```
Sub foo2()
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\" 'path to folder
exists = fso.FolderExists(Path)

If (exists) Then
    program = "saplogon.exe" 'Program name to run
    shl.Run (Path & program) 'Run a program
Else
    Path = "C:\Program Files\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\"
    program = "saplogon.exe" 'Program name to run
    shl.Run (Path & program) 'Run a program

End If
    Set sapConn = CreateObject("SAP.Functions") 'Create ActiveX object
    sapConn.Connection.ApplicationServer = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"
    sapConn.Connection.Client = "100" ' only read access
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Xabier , but it is giving compile error for the Path =